# How do I format a Seagate Expansion Desktop drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I have a Seagate Expansion Desktop drive model STBV3000200 (which I believe is the same as the STBV3000100, except for the power supply). It is also known by its "Regulatory Model" number SRD00F2. It consists of a Seagate enclosure with a ST3000DM001 hard drive inside.

Immediately after unboxing the drive, I ran the destructive badblocks test in preparation for putting a Linux filesystem on the drive.

I have discovered however, that there are conflicts between the formatting software and tools that actually access the filesystem, in particular, with regard to the logical sector size. So when I attempted to create a 256 GB partition (which appeared successful according to gdisk -l), I ended up with only a 32 GB partition.

Some output:

```
# gdisk -l /dev/sdx

[...]

Disk /dev/sdd: 732566645 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 4096 bytes

[...]


# parted -l

[...]

Model: Seagate Expansion Desk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdx: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B

[...]


# lsblk -o SIZE,PHY-SEC,LOG-SEC /dev/sdx
 SIZE PHY-SEC LOG-SEC
 2.7T    4096    4096



# hdparm -I /dev/sdx

[...]

Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors: 5860533168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:     2861588 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     3000592 MBytes (3000 GB)

[...]


# smartctl -a -d sat /dev/sdx

[...]

User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical

[...]
```

Versions of the various tools:

```
sys-apps/gptfdisk-0.8.10  
sys-apps/hdparm-9.39  
sys-apps/smartmontools-6.1  
sys-apps/util-linux-2.24.1-r3  
sys-block/parted-3.1-r1  
sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-3.10.17
```

It seems this would work if I could just get all of the tools and libraries to see the hard drive in the same way, but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same drive, and similar issues.  I even went as far as replacing the drive under warranty, but continued to have the same problem.
I believe that the issue is with the small circuit board that translates USB to SATA in the caddy, the drive itself is fine.

I removed the hard drive from the caddy and the issues disappeared.  I tested over various PCs and operating systems.  The caddy always introduced a layer of fault, which disappeared when not used.  I even tried with another caddy (different brand), the fault did not return.

A paticularly nasty implication, is that if you move either way between the seagate caddy and any other method of connecting the drive, the operating systems no longer see the formatted partition, so you cannot access any data... bad if it is critical and the circuitboard itself has failed... you would need to obtain a new caddy circuit board of the same design to regain your data.

I will not use the caddy, I do not accept the risk.  I just use the hard drive out of it now.  As an aside, I have always loved Seagate drives.

I do not believe you can get by this issue in the software layer.  Using the caddy circuit will always cause an odd translation of the drive architecture.  What you do with it now is up to you... but if you can afford to write off your warranty on the caddy... do what I did, take the drive out and see if that sorts out your problem.

I have notified Seagate of my observations.